# how to reload calling fragment with the previous state and set the result got as a callback from the dialog fragment it initiated

Tags: android, fragment

This is how my application runs.
The application has several fragments as view pager connecting through main activity. From Second Fragment, I launched custom fragment dialog and upon ok button click inside that fragment dialog, I am fetching the result into main activity. I am using `android.support.v4` library.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MyDialog.Communicator {

private static String callBackMessage;  
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                return FirstFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(MainActivity.this);
            default:
                return ThirdFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }

@Override
public void onDialogMessage(String callBackMessage) {
    MainActivity.callBackMessage = callBackMessage;
}

public static String getCallBackMessage() {
    return callBackMessage;
}
```

This is my MyDialog Fragment class, here I am creating some rows and giving checkboxes to be selected.

```
private void performOKButtonFunctionality() {
    String msg = checkedBoxesCount + "";
    communicator.onDialogMessage(msg);

    SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
    secondFragment.testFunction(row);
    dismiss();
}
```

Now because of my very early days into android and its fragment life cycle, I am calling a method on Second fragment after instantiating it. the row parameter just passes the row number.

Now inside the Second Fragment Class I have some thing like,

```
public void testFunction(String callBackRow) {
    callBackRowNo = Integer.parseInt(callBackRow);
    String callBackMessage = MainActivity.getCallBackMessage();
    getTableData(callBackMessage + "");
}
```

In order to save the SecondFragment previous state, I am saving its context by making it static like this,

```
private static Context activityContext;

public static SecondFragment newInstance(Context context) {
    activityContext = context;
    SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}
```

Now doing so, I am able to use my Second Fragment only one time after clicking the ok button from Fragment Dialog. but upon clicking again, the app crashes at this point.

```
FragmentManager myDialogManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

The raised exception is:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
> ```

Now, my questions are:

1. How do we reenter into the oncreate method of the fragment where it just restores its previous state rather than saving it explicitly before launching 
   fragment dialog.
2. How does the fragment dialog pass parameter to the fragment which can be used to update the fragment field.
   Is there some easy way to achieve this?
   Before asking I searched the SO but could not find anything where this scenario was asked or explained.

I am badly stuck here and any solution/direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

when do you make fragment with `newInstace`, you can put argsments like this.

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int value) {
    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("value", value);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

it also needs constructor MyFragment()

```
public MyFragment() {}
```

get values from args like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        value = getArguments().getInt("value");
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
}
```